Is there a way to have a Cell in google sheets increase or decrease based on the number in another cell?
I want to have a vaule in my google sheet increase when above a number e.g. when above  20 it will increase by 1,000 for every 1 it goes up but is there anyway to have it work that way and when it is below 20 it decreases by 1,000 for every 1 and have that  outcome reflected into a cell where the value begins at a number e.g 50,000 and will decrease and increase based on the number in the other cell?
** Example **
Cell 1 27 cell 2 57,000 Cell 1 13 Cell 2 43,000
I've tried to find anyway of doing this, but im yet to be successful any ideas are appreciated, im happy to try pretty much anything to get this to work

If your Cell 1 is A1, then in Cell 2 you can put the formula =50000+(A1-20)*1000
